# Segues does not take user from Slide-Out menu to next view

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, segue

So, Im developing an app with a slide-out menu, where I have used the tutorial and project-files from AppCoda (http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/).

This slide-out menu is created by JSON from a database, and is working as it should, however, when I press one of the cells, it won't load the new ViewController.

I have tried using this code, to make it work:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender: (id) sender {
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
Rules *currentRule = [rulesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UINavigationController *destViewController = (UINavigationController*)segue.destinationViewController;
destViewController.title = [currentRule.ruleTitle capitalizedString];

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRule"]) {
    PhotoViewController *pvc = (PhotoViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    pvc.people = currentRule.rulePeople;
    pvc.content = currentRule.ruleText;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:pvc animated:YES];
}

if ([segue isKindOfClass: [SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]]) {
    SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;

    swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc) {
        UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
        [navController setViewControllers: @[dvc] animated: NO ];
        [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
    };
} }
```

The segue, combining the two views is attached to the TableView (the menu) and the PhotoView. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that code is ever called?

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner In the PhotoViewController there are these two lines, which (I assume) should do the trick:
_sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
_sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

Comment: If you have not set a debugging point in your code it's impossible to say if it gets called or not... just because actions are set does not mean it's loading the right view controller, for example.